# jQuery tab not working

Tags: jquery

I am creating the tab using jQuery:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

and the html:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin ur nec arcu m sodal mpus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
        <p> llus p Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
        <p> sus he  nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>

</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

and the jQuery I have included is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but the tab is not working?

Comment: Seems to [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/VYgYj/). But note that usually you would want `$(document)`, without the quotes. It won't make a difference, but it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Did you include the css file for jQuery UI?

Comment: @JamesAllardice but the same code i am using and its not working

Comment: @Podge ya i have included the css too

Comment: @Mayankswami can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your **exact** code

Comment: are you using any other library like `prototype`?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I am using the same tab.  Me too had the same problem because i included prototype library for calendar.After removing it its working perfect for me

Comment: @Limi Jerin: That's why I am asking, because with jQuery if you use any other library like proptotype so these type of errors may occur.

Comment: i have got my problem solved after including the correct jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove double quotes from `$("document")`

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Or Try with:

```
$(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
})
```

**EDITED:**

**Suggestion Note:** If everything is fine then these type of errors may occur while you are using any other library like `prototype` then it is being conflicting with jQuery library, to remove conflicts you've to go through with `jQuery.noConflict( [removeAll] )`.

See reference for implementation: **[jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

Comment: It won't make a difference. You can select anything (or nothing) and `ready` will still behave the same.

Comment: @Mayank swami: are you using any other library like prototype?